# Trouble declaring a string array in a yup schema

Tags: typescript, react-hook-form, yup

I have a form that contains a [multi select](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#multiple-values), so I have the following type definition:

```
export type Fields = {
    spokenLanguages: string[];
    // other fields
};
```

Then I define a yup schema for the array as described in their [docs](https://github.com/jquense/yup?tab=readme-ov-file#array):

```
export const FieldsSchema = yup.object({
    spokenLanguages: yup.array(yup.string()).required("This field is required"),
    // other fields
});
```

I have also tried with `array().of(yup.string())`

When I add the validation to my (react-hook-form) form, I get:

> Type '{ spokenLanguages: (string | undefined)[]; }' is not assignable
> to type 'Fields' (which is string[])

I thought it would be a common question since it is a normal string array, but I have searched far and wide with no luck.

If I just declare the array and not the type of it, the error disappears:

```
yup.array().required("This field is required")
```

but shouldn't I declare the type of the array? Furthermore if I make the string type required, the error disappears, but I am not sure what it actually means.

```
array().of(yup.string().required()).required("Required")
```

If you want to see where I declare the schema validation:

```
const { register } = useForm<Fields>({
    resolver: yupResolver(FieldsSchema),
});
```